# How to remove filter holder out of Brita water filter jug?

Tags: kitchen, water

When I cleaned my Brita water filter jug, I accidentally placed the filter holder in the wrong orientation.

As a result, the filter holder is stuck in the water filter jug.

I tried very hard to remove it, but I did not manage to do it.

Is it possible to take the filter holder out of the jug?
If yes, please advise.

I have attached an image for your reference.

[image: stuck filter holder in Brita Water jug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me too.  Part of the problem is that it's hard to grab the filter holder.

So find a wire coat hanger (or something similar) and straighten it. Bend a hook into one end of it. Lower that into the filter holder and hook the bent end around the bottom of the filter holder. You can then pull the coat hanger up, maybe with jerking motions, to pull the filter holder out of the pitcher.

In the picture below, the red thing is the wire coat hanger.

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: I always love your detailed Sketches. Still have to resize them, though ;)

Comment: Thanks @Alex! I'll try to remember to make them a more reasonable size in the future! ;-)

Comment: @BrettFromLA just add an "m" to the end of the image-link. See my edit for reference. That way you can still have a link to the full size image in case someone needs the details. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Alex WOW! I didn't know about that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I've made this same mistake many times myself and it always frees-up if you just wiggle it around a little. The material of the jug and the funnel are both very strong so don't be afraid to apply a little force to them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wash them with soap and then pull them apart as @Lefty said, because the soap will act as a lubricant.

Answer (score 1):

Dip the bottom part into very hot water for some 15 seconds. The heat will cause "slight stretching" of the outer piece. Then wiggle the stuck part out.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. I took the filter out and then put a tea towel down on the counter and smacked the jug against it (so the open bit was hitting the counter)... it ended up falling out.

Answer (score 1):

Hot water worked for me - jug and cartridge holder already sitting in hot washing up water, because I was about to wash it when I realised it was stuck, so probably had longer than 15 seconds.
In as long as it had taken me to find and read the answers here, the top slipped out easily.
I did fill the jug completely to the top with hot water; after immersing it in the sink, I topped up to overflowing by ladling it in with a mug.

Try this solution first - lot less hassle and less danger of damage/scratches to self or jug than the coat hanger option!